# No key with alias 'key1' found in keystore /Users/ralucaraluca/upload-keystore.jks

Tags: flutter

Hey I get this error when I try to deploy my flutter app  using flutter build appbundle.
Any idea how I can resolve this? I tried to modify key alias with key1 , key0 , key , but nothing work.
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: The keyAlias needs to be the same that you used when created the .jks file, is not a random one, you need to remember which one you put on the .jks file.

Comment: I didn't put any key , I just added the password 2 times and my first and last name , and get this [ storing /Users/ralucaraluca/upload-keystore.jks ]

Comment: in this case maybe you need to create another one and place an alias on it, cause the gradle will look for an alias inside the key.

Comment: there is a code for replacing? because I just deleted the file upload-keystore.jks and if I run again the code like  keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 and is saying that already exist

Comment: Tried create with another name?

Comment: When I put password I get this error

Comment: I tried with another pass and it worked but look : https://imgur.com/a/7MnCDLR it didn't said to put a key

Comment: You could try create in another folder and then copy the file to there. I always used the Android Studio for creating that keys, so never used the command tool.